# Can't get SignalR work with two Hubs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, signalr

I've started digging in SignalR 0.4 and got stuck on a problem. I'd like to have two different Hubs on the same page which to keep things simple are:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message) 
    {
        Clients.addMessage(message);
    }
}

public class Chat2Hub : Hub
{
    public void Send2(string message) 
    {
        Clients.addMessage2(message);
    }
}
```

This is my client code:

```
function initChat() {
    var chat = $.connection.chat;

    chat.addMessage = function (message) {...};
    $('.send-cmd').click(function () {...});

    return $.connection.hub.start();
}

function initChat2() {
    var chat2 = $.connection.chat2;

    chat2.addMessage2 = function (message) {...};
    $('.send2-cmd').click(function () {...});

    return $.connection.hub.start();
}

$(function() {
    initChat().done(function() {
        initChat2();
    });
});
```

Simple enough, but I cannot make them work together. In this example, "chat" works correctly and "chat2" fails (without errors).
If I reverse order of initialization of course the opposite happens.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you starting the hub connection twice. There's one connection for all hubs so you only need to call $.connection.hub.start() once.

Comment: It doesn't work. There's also a check in signalR.start() which check if there's already a transport available and resolve immediatly the promise. Great library BTW :-)

Comment: What doesn't work? Calling start once? You have a bunch of issues with the code. You need to subscribe to all events on all hubs before calling start.

Comment: You're (of course) right. hub.start() must be called after all the wire up is done.